# Retreat Weeks/Months/Years from a simple date Input

Tags: mysql

Considering the date "2018-01-29" (VAR_5) as a single input,

```
SELECT

DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-29','%v/%Y') AS VAR_5, 
DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-22','%v/%Y') AS VAR_4, 
DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-15','%v/%Y') AS VAR_3, 
DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-08','%v/%Y') AS VAR_2, 
DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-01','%v/%Y') AS VAR_1, 
DATE_FORMAT('2017-12-25','%v/%Y') AS VAR_0
```

How can I go back in time only from that date?
Instead of manually entering the remaining dates? ('2018-01-22','2018-01-15','2018-01-08','2018-01-01','2017-12-25')

I need something like an Loop inside mysql ...

** In this case I want to retreat Weeks .

Intended Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeZWs.jpg)

Comment: can you clarify your question more, like do you need to make a `query` which will automatically give you the dates?

Comment: try using the function `DATE_ADD(VAR_5, INTERVAL -7 DAY);`. This will give you the date 1 week before `VAR_5`. To go further, simply loop using a counter, something like `DATE_ADD(VAR_5, INTERVAL -(MyCounter * 7) DAY);` where `MyCounter` starts from 1 and goes up (back in time) as far as you wish.

Comment: because I do this before with PHP, and wanted to get a more direct way from a single date in mysql .

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence table containing integer values (eg. `helper.seq(i)` with values `1, 2, 3, ...`) you can do the following:

```
select '2018-01-29' - interval (s.i-1) week as dt
from helper.seq as s
where s.i <= 6
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/SOA75169

You can replace `week` with `day`, `month` or `year`.

Comment: It works . Thank you . 
Last doubt, how can i convert the same output dates to a DATE_FORMAT(MyDate,'%v/%Y') to display the results that way "04/2018" (In Case of the Week Interval) ?

Comment: @IvoRubim `DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-29' - interval (s.i-1) week,'%v/%Y')`

Comment: Thanks . With PHP i get this, and works well ::

$MyQuery = 
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE('{$MyDate}') - INTERVAL (S.I-1) {$MyInterval}),'{$SqlDateFormat') AS VAR FROM HELPER_SEQ AS S WHERE S.I <= 6"